# PowerShell 5.1 & PowerShell 7 same script, different outcomes

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, powershell-5.1

I am trying to run this script:

```
$dll = Add-Type -Path \\machineX\Folder\\AL.Scripting.dll
New-Object AL.Scripting.BsmScriptObject
```

When running on PS 5.1 everything runs fine, but when ran on PW 7 I get:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
(Error importing Scripting Object DLL.Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s):
 "Method not found: 'Void System.AppDomainSetup.set_ApplicationBase(System.String)'.")
```

I am trying to make this PW command result accessible through .NET Core API, but it seems it's to be impossible, because .NET Core solutions can use only PowerShell 6.0-7.0 versions. Maybe is there any workarounds?

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 runs on the .NET Framework 4.0 runtime, PowerShell 7 uses the newer .NET Core runtime. If `AL.Scripting.dll` was compiled for .NET Framework it indeed won't work with the .NET Core runtime. You'll need to re-compile it. If `AL.Scripting` is vendor-supplied, ask the vendor if they have a newer version of the library

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Maybe it's possible to launch process of PW 5.1 in .Net Core application? Since PW 5.1 is installed anyways

Comment: Absolutely! Nothing stops you from doing `powershell -File C:\scriptWithAlScriptingRoutine.ps1` from `pwsh`